# Why do sharp gradient transitions render blurry in firefox?

Tags: css, linear-gradients, gradient, css-gradients

Here is the problem I'm facing: **Chrome** [image] **Firefox**.

I feel like there should be a way to create sharp crisp transitions with gradients, and there IS. By placing two twin color nodes a few pixels apart, and then a unique color node on the same pixel as the second twin, a sharp color transition is created.

But usually I use Firefox, not chrome. And for the longest time I thought that maybe my method was wishy washy because it really only worked at intervals of five pixels. So it was very unreliable. But recently I discovered that Chrome is spot on. So I put together a test snippet which I'll show you below demonstrating the behavior precisely.

Can someone tell me why this behavior occurs, and what I can do about it?

```css
.demo {
  
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-align: center;

}


.demo:after {
  content: 'CRISP';
  color: white;
}


.one {

  background-image: linear-gradient(black 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(90deg, red 42px, #0F0 42px, #0F0 84px, blue 84px);
  height: 42px; width: 126px;

}


.two {

  background-image: linear-gradient(black 2px, transparent 2px), linear-gradient(90deg, red 42px, #0F0 42px, #0F0 84px, blue 84px);
  height: 42px; width: 126px;

}


.three {

  background-image: linear-gradient(black 3px, transparent 3px), linear-gradient(90deg, red 42px, #0F0 42px, #0F0 84px, blue 84px);
  height: 42px; width: 126px;

}


.four {

  background-image: linear-gradient(black 4px, transparent 4px), linear-gradient(90deg, red 42px, #0F0 42px, #0F0 84px, blue 84px);
  height: 42px; width: 126px;

}


.five {

  background-image: linear-gradient(black 5px, transparent 5px), linear-gradient(90deg, red 42px, #0F0 42px, #0F0 84px, blue 84px);
  height: 42px; width: 126px;

}


.six {

  background-image: linear-gradient(black 6px, transparent 6px), linear-gradient(90deg, red 42px, #0F0 42px, #0F0 84px, blue 84px);
  height: 42px; width: 126px;

}
```

```html
What you see (unless you're experiencing the same problem I am):<br />
<div style="width: 776px;">
  
<div class="demo one"></div>
<div class="demo two"></div>
<div class="demo three"></div>
<div class="demo four"></div>
<div class="demo five"></div>
<div class="demo six"></div>

</div><br />

What I see:<br />
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/dvxszeJ.png" /><br /><br />

Don't let the even odd pattern fool you though... A different test run produced these results:<br />
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/f4nWWtF.png" />
```

Here's a better look at the misbehaving boxes:
[image]

**I have been asked to provide the exact line of code for the problematic black to transparent gradient**

```
div.fluxclass { /*which gradients are effected depend on seemingly random circumstances*/
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 5px, transparent 5px);
}
```

Comment: i am confused, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXjOPB (zoom x 12 on hover ). it looks sharp to me in chrome, FF, opera, IE, Do you have an issue with a specific browser/OS ?

Comment: I hadn't thought to check actually. Hang on I'll be back.

Comment: Okay just tried using chrome and quite right, it does seem to be sharp at all values... Let's see I'm using windows 10 64 bit and firefox 44.0.2 and my zoom is at 100%. I used the the default value button to snap it back there just to be sure. What other things should I check?

Comment: Which gradient are you talking about? The black one or the colored ones? If it is the black one, can you show us the exact code which you had used to create that picture? There seems to be two layers (of top to bottom) in that one.

Comment: The black to transparent gradient is visibly problematic in the first, second, third, fourth and sixth panels of the diagram I provided. The fifth panel contains the only crisp transition of the black to transparent gradient, presumably because the nodes have been stopped on an interval of 5. The red, green and blue gradient transitions on intervals of 5. If they did not, likely they would also produce fuzzy transitions.

Comment: Try playing with [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering)

Comment: Oriol - image-rendering doesn't seem to have any noticeable effect on gradients, only scaled images.

Comment: @Musixauce3000 You are right, I got confused. The CSS Working Group considered taking `image-rendering` into account for gradients, but I think there was no resolution.

Comment: I don't see what you see in (a) Chrome v43 on Win 7 (b) Firefox v38 on Win 7 (c) Chrome v50 (dev-m) on Win 10 (d) Firefox v44 on Win 10.

Comment: Would you mind uploading some screen shots of what you do see?  Because I've run plenty tests since this post and found that this is a problem Firefox seems to be experiencing across all windows operating systems.